# Best algorithm for x% chance of happening?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, statistics, probability

I need to make an event occur on a configurable x% of pageviews across all pageviews.

I want to make sure I'm thinking of the probability correctly here.

The following code runs every single pageview.

**if I want event to occur 99% of the time**

```
do_thing if SecureRandom.random_number(1..100) <= 99
```

**if I want event to occur 10% of the time**

```
do_thing if SecureRandom.random_number(1..100) <= 10
```

I know there are subtle nuance "gotchas" in probability and I wanted to make sure this is the best approach.

Comment: I don't see any issue with this

Comment: No issues, though SecureRandom and initializing a range is probably overkill for this. `if rand < 0.99` should work just as good.

Comment: @Tallboy : Your approach looks good to me, but I would use `SecureRandom.random_number(100) == 0` instead.

Comment: If you don't want to reinvent the wheel you could use https://github.com/splitrb/split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is ok in terms of probability calculations. But I would use the ruby method `Kernel#rand` instead to save some space:

`rand * 100 <= 99`
or
`rand(1..100) <= 99`